# "Invalid python interpreter selected" prompt vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interpreter

I've been trying to setup my python workspace on vscode but the software doesn't seem to pick up the fact that I have python installed, and keeps telling me to install python. I've tried manually adding the path of the .exe file but the "invalid interpreter prompt" shows up every single time. Just for proof of me having the correct path in the settings here's a screenshot of the [.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJj2j.png) and
[the command prompts I used to obtain the path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt3BU.png)

Comment: Maybe try restarting VS Code (from the command palette) or your computer? Also, VS Code might not have permissions to access/run that executable, so make sure to run it as an administrator.

Comment: I tried reinstalling both vscode and python through the instructions from the command palette, and ran vscode as administrator but nothing made a difference. I added the python.exe file location to PATH as well

Comment: I'm having the same problem here after I upgraded my python to 3.10.6 (LATEST at the time of writing). VS Code is reporting `An Invalid Python interpreter is selected, please try changing it to enable features such as IntelliSense, linting, and debugging.` and not accepting any virtual envs created with this version of python.

Comment: Same for me, I even tried installing older (3.9/3.8) python versions and it still comes up with the same message. I'm wondering if the extension is running some python code (eg to get version etc) and getting an unexpected response?.

Comment: Is there any progress on the issue?

Comment: I ended up downgrading the VS Code Python extension to v10.1 (from v12.0) and it seems to have fixed the problem with the warning popup, but when I try to use Jupyter it's still telling me that python is not installed..

Answer (score 28):

On my device (VSCode 1.71.2, Python extension 2022.14.0) I could solve the problem by clearing the python interpreter setting.

For this, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette. Then, enter `Python: Clear Workspace Interpreter Setting`. On the next panel, select to delete all.

After this, you should be able to select an interpreter by entering `Python:Select Interpreter` in the command palette.

Comment: this solved my problem, but I still don't understand why... could you provide further explanation of what happened under the hood? At first, I thought I was having problems with PATH, but now I am even more confused.

Comment: On newer versions of VSCode, this is now called "Python: Clear Cache and Reload Windows"

Comment: Python: Clear Workspace Interpreter Setting also exists, but 'Python: Clear Cache and Reload Windows' is what solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you have the [**python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension installed.

Then follow the steps below to choose an *interpreter* for vscode:

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette
2. search for `Python:Select Interpreter` (or click select interpreter in the lower right corner)

   [image]
3. If the panel shows an interpreter, select the available interpreter. If the panel doesn't have an interpreter option. Please select the first item `Enter interpreter path`

   [image]
4. Then paste the full path to your `python.exe` (or go to explorer by selecting `Find` and select your `python.exe`)

   [image]

If it still fails, try installing the **pre-release python** extension.

[image]

Comment: Tried all of this, including the pre-release version of the python extension. Still no luck.

Comment: i did exactly these steps this morning and it worked for me. it found the three different python executables in my path.  not sure if i restarted vscode after. i think so - after all, it is a microsoft product.

Answer (score 3):

For me, after investigating the problem in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19692), I found that the problem had to do with my `ComSpec` environment variable. This environment variable needs to be set to `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` for the python extension to work.

Make sure to restart after changing the environment variable for changes to take effect

Comment: I had lost hope but as a final resort, I tried this and it worked for me

Comment: this one fixed the problem for me, as i have in the past changed the ComSpec trying to experiment with windows terminal commands

Answer (score 2):

Re-Create the virtual venv solved it

Answer (score 2):

Remove any blank spaces in your folder path. For me, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions above, none worked. I even tried reinstalling it, no luck.

What worked was downgrading to the previous version (in my case `v2022.12.1`) of the [Python vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) then upgrading to the latest (which was `v2022.12.1`).

Answer (score 0):

Running VS Code as administrator helped with solving the invalid python interpreter problem.

Answer (score 0):

what fixed it for me was going to settings -> search "inherit env" and disable it.

(macos)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by, re-creating the environment with no spaces or underlines (_) in the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

### What solved my problem was:

It seemed that the autopep8 formatter was the main reason but I did all of this steps:

- !! deleted the autopep8 extention & the configs related in the workspace-settings.json & in the user-settings.json
- deleted the venv
- deleted the python.defaultInterpreter setting in workspace-settings.json
- deleted the python extention

after deleting these things, I installed:

- python extention
- recreated the venv
- reloaded the window and selected the venv/bin/python in select interpreter command in the pallete
- optional: installed autopep8 & configured it in the workspace-settings.json like this:

  ```
    "settings": {
        "[python]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
        }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Visual Studio Code previously worked and then you wake up one morning, it doesn't, the simplest explanation for this error is when Windows operating system does an automatic restart after X hours or X days, and Visual Studio Code opens up automatically on its own because it was previously open before the restart.  Windows is not smart enough to open Visual Studio Code "as an Administrator".

***To resolve this error, simply close Visual Studio Code and reopen "as an Administrator".***

> Note: My observation skills were tip top shape today and finally
> figured out "how the rabbit got in the fenced in garden" problem based on the
> movie Phenomenon.  I can't even count how many times this happens to me.