# VSCode says my interpreter is invalid, tried all fixes in the web to no avail

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

If anyone can help, please do so as I have been trying to fix this for hours to no avail. And yes I have tried numerous solutions found on Google, Stack Overflow, and even Reddit.

I have been using Python with VSCode for the longest time but now it suddenly doesn't work. I'm on version 3.10.7 (Windows) as seen below:
[image: Python version in powershell terminal]

As you can see it asks me to select the interpreter. I actually did by clicking that and selecting the interpreter. But when I do this comes out:

[image: Invalid interpreter]

Here is my settings.json file, on the python portion:

[image: settings.json]

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling both python and VSCode, as well as switching to pre-release version of the Python extension, still does not do it.

I also have my PATH folder include Python folders.
[image: PATH environmental variables]

Hope anyone can help T-T

**EDIT:**

Here are my environmental variables
[image: Environmental Variables]

Here's what my Select Interpreter interface shows
[image]

Finally found a solution!
I downgraded the Python extension for vscode to 10.1
[image: Install another version]

Code works as intended but interpreter still not detected
[image]

Comment: Did you try the things described here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73263592/invalid-python-interpreter-selected-prompt-vscode

Comment: Yes, that was the first post that I saw and tried that. My comspec is also correct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is your interface of "Select Interpreter"? Whether the update or restart vscode is valid

Comment: I edited the post to show more screenshots!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the pre-release version of python. If it is invalid, try to reinstall vscode.

[image]

Comment: I switched to an older version instead and it worked. Still doesn't recognize my interpreter but at least the code runs now.

Comment: @Pongbao It seems that this is not a good phenomenon. Although it can temporarily solve the problem, I suggest you reinstall vscode

Comment: I actually already did that more than twice but the error persists. Maybe in a future update in the extension, this would be solved.