# VS Code - An Invalid Python interpreter is selected, please try changing it to enable features such as IntelliSense, linting, and debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to select my python interpreter in VS Code using a venv that I have created. I have tried everything but it doesn't work.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
- practice
 - venv
  - Scripts
   - python.exe
   - all other associated venv files.
```

I then use `Python: Select interpreter` and use path `practice\venv\Scripts` I have also tried `practice\venv\Scripts\python.exe`

However I get the following error:

```
An Invalid Python interpreter is selected, please try changing it to enable features such as IntelliSense, linting, and debugging.
```

Why is this an invalid python interpreter?

Comment: Did you try to set the absolute path (probably beginning with C:\\)?

Comment: @kzi Yes. I just tried relative too `venv\Scripts` but that doesn't work

Comment: Instead of wasting much time with trial and error, I would just install python system-wide if that's possible. The installer should add the directory of the interpreter to the path, so VS Code can find it.

Comment: @kzi I can do this and it runs fine but this stops me using isolated environments for different projects.

Comment: you should still be able to use your own `python.exe` file for executing your code if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73839755/18359438) solve your issue?